# How to reset boost::sml::sm instance

Tags: c++, boost, state-machine

It seems that `boost::sml::sm` doesn't have any specific reset method and it lacks a move assignment operator so I can't do something like assign a fresh instance (e.g. `machine = boost::sml::sm<MyMachine>{}`). My current approach is an ugly trick to call dtor and ctor in place:

```
machine.~sm();
new (&machine) std::decay_t<decltype(machine)>();
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Just do as you would always do (i.e. never what you actually wrote): use a wrapper to manage the lifetime, e.g. using `optional` or `unique_ptr`.

Example:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e9c8c0aa47c8d5e2)</kbd>**

```
//
// Copyright (c) 2016-2018 Kris Jusiak (kris at jusiak dot net)
//
// Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0.
// (See accompanying file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at
// http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
//
#include <boost/sml.hpp>
#include <cassert>

namespace sml = boost::sml;

namespace {
// events
struct release {};
struct ack {};
struct fin {};
struct timeout {};

// guards
const auto is_ack_valid = [](const ack&) { return true; };
const auto is_fin_valid = [](const fin&) { return true; };

// actions
const auto send_fin = [] {};
const auto send_ack = [] {};

struct hello_world {
  auto operator()() const {
    using namespace sml;
    // clang-format off
    return make_transition_table(
      *"established"_s + event<release> / send_fin = "fin wait 1"_s,
       "fin wait 1"_s + event<ack> [ is_ack_valid ] = "fin wait 2"_s,
       "fin wait 2"_s + event<fin> [ is_fin_valid ] / send_ack = "timed wait"_s,
       "timed wait"_s + event<timeout> / send_ack = X
    );
    // clang-format on
  }
};
}

#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
  using namespace sml;

  boost::optional<sm<hello_world> > m;

  static_assert(2 == sizeof(m), "sizeof(m) != 2b");

  auto run = [&] {
      assert(m->is("established"_s));

      m->process_event(release{});
      assert(m->is("fin wait 1"_s));

      m->process_event(ack{});
      assert(m->is("fin wait 2"_s));

      m->process_event(fin{});
      assert(m->is("timed wait"_s));

      m->process_event(timeout{});
      assert(m->is(X));  // released
  };

  for (auto i : {1,2,3}) {
      std::cout << "Run " << i << "\n";
      m.emplace(); // default constructs a sm in-place
      run();
  }
}
```

Prints

```
Run 1
Run 2
Run 3
```

Comment: Sample now [Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e9c8c0aa47c8d5e2)

Comment: Thanks. I'll help another time. (Hint: I didn't say unique_ptr has no overhead, and whether `optional` "changes semantics" is debatable. Just file a feature request at the `Boost Sml` library, I suppose.)

Comment: PS. I was just pointing out that arbitrary limitations require you to solve them. You could of course think of a custom life-time adaptor and call it `reinitializable<T>` or something. Seems like this could be in your recipe: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/launder